# Google sheet script - Stop filling an array comparing to another one when common value met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I tried all day long to filter 2 columns containing text values with simple a query(A1:B;"select A where A<>B") or =filter(), so I tried scripting but i'm also missing something. By this way, I want to slice a first array filled when a common value is found in another array. Could somebody please help ? Here is the code:

```js
function filterAll(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('temp1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var data1 = sheet.getRange(1, 4, lastRow).getValues();
  var tab1 = [];
  tab1.push(data1[0]);

  var data2 = sheet.getRange(1, 3, lastRow).getValues();
  var tab2 = [];
  tab2.push(data2[0]);

  // var subarray = []; // for subarray = tab2.slice(1,n)

  for (var n = 1; n < data1.length; n++) {
    if (tab1.join().indexOf(data1[n].join()) == -1) { 
      tab1.push(data1[n])  
    };
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, tab1.length, tab1[0].length).setValues(tab1);

  for (var n = 1; n < data2.length; n++){
    if (tab2.join().indexOf(data2[n].join()) == -1) {
      for (var z = 1; z < data1.length; z++){ 
        if (data2[n] === data1[z]){ 
          break;  
        } else { 
          tab2.push(data2[n]); 
        } 
      }
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, tab2.length, tab2[0].length).setValues(tab2);
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sheet sample?

Comment: Thank you for answering, here's an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dNU2Li43AjwExcy2iX9-C1c177LAIns5Qj1a9aYrUVI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a formula you can try

```
=FILTER(
  A2:A,
  ISNA(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B4,0)),
  ROW(A2:A)<MIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MATCH(B2:B4,A:A,0))))
)
```

[image]

If you need a script you can use the main approach

```
/**
*
* @param {Array.<Array.<object>>} arr data
* @param {Array.<object>} list the list for comparing
* @param {number} colIndex The column of the data for comparing
*/
function filterUntilAnyOfList_(arr, list, colIndex) {
  var res = [];
  arr.some(function(row) {    
    if(list.indexOf(row[colIndex]) === -1){
      res.push(row);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  return res.length ? res : '';
}
```

For a function in your project it would be

```
/**
* Action
*/
function userAction() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  .getRange('Filter!A2:A')
  .getValues();
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  .getRange('Filter!B2:B3')
  .getValues()
  .map(function(row) {
    return row[0];
  });
  Logger.log(filterUntilAnyOfList_(data, list, 0));
}
```

For a custom formula it can be used too

```
/**
* @customformula
*/
function INLIST(data, list, col) {
  data = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [[data]];
  list = (Array.isArray(list) ? list : [[list]]).map(function(row) {
    return row[0];
  });
  return filterUntilAnyOfList_(data, list, col - 1);
}
```

[image]

[My sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13eQK1AnqsGkVCPgqF7LGoOrxOPEJqf7RzpNsETeU59s/edit?usp=sharing)

Get your choice!

Comment: Thank you very very much, your solutions work well ! I don't want to bother but In fact I didn't explain so well. I have added a line in my example so I think It is clearer. After all, I think this is isn't possible by formula, only by scripting. So the problem would be stop filling an array when value met in second array, as said in the title of my demand and showed in my script with the double iteration

Comment: (Edit : a second iteration in a first one)

Comment: for (var n = 1; n < data2.length; n++){
    if (tab2.join().indexOf(data2[n].join()) == -1) {
      for (var z = 1; z < data1.length; z++){

Comment: So great ! Exactly what I wanted, you saved my life hihi. Thank you three thousand times !! God bless you

Comment: PS : your code doesn't work if there is only one common value in each column. Ex: AAA in Col1 and AAA in Col2.. I don't understand all your code yet, could you please quickly fix that, I guess by an exception aka if list.length = 1 etc

Comment: @Nad there is a typo. It should be `list = (Array.isArray(list) ? list : [[list]])`

Comment: THANK YOU ! I won't bother you anymore :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your issue, I'd suggest:

- if you want to retain only values that ARE found on the second array:

  `=filter(A1:A,match(A1:A,B1:B,0))`
- if you want to retain only values the are NOT found in the second array:

  `=filter(A1:A,isna(match(A1:A,B1:B,0)))`

If I misunderstood your request, it might be useful if you could share an example of your sheet and describe with concrete examples what the expected outcome would be for a given input (as requested already in a comment to your original post).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Here is a sample https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dNU2Li43AjwExcy2iX9-C1c177LAIns5Qj1a9aYrUVI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Then that would be my second formula above, I guess

Comment: Thank you too Benoît Wéry, very nice to you ! and sorry for not having well explained myself